# Changing the anchor point of marker after it's added

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When creating a google maps marker, the performance may differ, when using icon parameter as object or as string.

load of:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng },
      map: this.map,
      icon: {url: iconUrl, anchor: anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 8)
});
```

is much slower than load of this:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng },
      map: this.map,
      icon: iconUrl
});
```

It can be visible when loading big amount of points which gives 4500ms vs 400ms.

As the icon used above is 16x16px circle, the anchor should be set in `google.maps.Point(8, 8)`.

Is it possible, to set anchor in different way or after the marker init?
The only way, I could find in google maps docs, is the way of passing anchor parameter in icon objects which requires url parameter.

Example (check the generation time in console): https://jsfiddle.net/ur76jckb/

No matter if icons is in base64, stored locally, extensions it has and the size of it. Just setting the field as object or as string makes a difference.

Google maps v3.34.16

[Bug reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119886490).

Comment: Strange. Never noticed that before. You could use the `setIcon()` method after the marker is created but I get roughly the same results doing it that way. Couldn't find an open issue either. You might want to open one in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853%20status:open).

Comment: @MrUpsidown i created one. I tried to workaround it in multiple ways, including setIcon after marker init but no luck unfortunately. This gets more problematic for larger applications with 50k+ points. the marker load just freezes the app for couple of seconds. Loading markers in chunks in timeouts, clusterer and loading markers in visible bounds helps in a way but you always have to sacrifice something other that way.

Comment: TBH, 50K markers at once sounds too much anyway so yes, you should think about clustering and/or only loading markers from a certain zoom level and only for the current bounds to avoid longer load times. Or maybe let your users choose via some setting, warning them that load times will be longer.

Comment: @MrUpsidown we already use that amount of elements. After marker creation actually it unexpectedly works fast. We also use clustering and other improvements. We can use api for loading markers in bounds, however, we often have dense marker areas and users may often move the map. This creates some unhandy situations. Marker loading/creation during map usage may create small freezes during map usage. Making marker creation time faster would enhance UX a lot. For example in app I'm working on now it's ~11seconds vs 900ms for 40K markers. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In order to change anchor of the marker icon after marker creation you can use the `setOptions()` method of the marker.

Have a look at the following example that creates a marker and changes its anchor after 3 second delay.

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.88, 151.28),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.781552, 151.274846),
        map: map,
        icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
    });
    
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        marker.setOptions({
            icon: { url:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(16,16)
            }
            
        });
    }, 3000);
            

}
```

```css
html, body, #map {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I did performance tests for 20K markers and it seems that with timeout after marker init it takes 3800ms to generate markers with anchor. It's still using icon object so that may be the problem. With url object it's 4500ms, with url string 450ms. So indeed there seems to be 700ms gain. However, the difference between this solution and init by icon string is still huge.

Comment: You may also try to use setOptions and just set the same icon without anchor (so actually no real change at all) and it will still take such time - 450ms for marker with icon string + 3350ms for setOptions with same icon but as object with url parameter.

Comment: It sounds like an API issue. Hopefully somebody from Google will look into this. I starred your bug report in Google issue tracker.

Comment: I did as well. I don't know what is going on with Google though. Seems like everyone is on holidays since a few months... I have legitimate bug reports in there since mid-August that are still in "new" status and nobody had a look at it yet. Really wonder what's going on as in the past they used to *at least* assign it to someone. Just look at the open issues list...

Comment: Oh wow... your issue was assigned right away. I must be very unlucky then :(